# With Angular HTTP client - How to send POST http object with all attribut `null by default`

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

My angular component:

```
const p: Product = this.products.find((d) => d === event.item.data);
p.name = 'foo';
```

My angular service is:

```
updateProduct(product: Product): Observable<CommonResult> {
    return this.http.put<CommonResult>(this.configService.getApiUri() + '/products/' + product.productId, product);
}
```

My Product model:

```
export class Product {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    category: string = null;
}
```

I want:

```
{
  id: 1
  name: "foo",
  category: null
}
```

but I have:

```
{
  id: 1
  name: "foo"
}
```

I do not access to my backend code (I can not change backend code). How to patch my Frontend code to fix my issue?

Comment: Show us the code that creates and populates the Product instance before sending it to the backend.

Comment: I edited my question with this information

Comment: That finds an existing product, and changes its name. Where is the existing product being created? Anyway, the problem is that the category is set to undefined, or that the product is not actually an instance of the class, or that the category is deleted. Set the category to null explicitly before sending it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I patch my update because my GET do not return category: null

```
{...new Product(), ...product}
```

full code:

```
updateProduct(product: Product): Observable<CommonResult> {
    return this.http.put<CommonResult>(this.configService.getApiUri() + '/products/' + product.productId, {...new Product(), ...product});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are never creating an object out of your class, therefore `category = null` will never be assigned. You used the class as it was an interface, declaring the properties but never creating an instance of it.

```
export class Product {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    category: string = null;
}
```

In order to set the category null, you would have to use `new Product()`, and possibly set up the constructor for other properties:

```
const productResult = this.products.find((d) => d === event.item.data);
const p: Product = new Product(productResult.id, 'foo');
```

Product class with constructor:

```
export class Product {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    category: string = null;

    constructor(id: number, name: string) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Now your object will have the `category` set to null